# Server http keep-alive to the client ip or session?

Tags: http, keep-alive

When a server sent a keep-alive header to a client

Does it mean that every requests of this client ip will be benefited?

Does it mean that every requests of this client ip plus session will be benefited?

Put it into a situation.

After I browse a website and the server sent keep-alive to me. I open another browser and go to the same website. Will my second request connect without handshake?

I read the documentation but I could not find out the target. Please help me.

Comment: If you open another browser, that's another session so will be another connection to the server.

Comment: Could I say the keep alive target is the client ip + the current session?

Comment: The client ip is part of what defines a session, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTTP 1.0, if both the client and server support keep alive then the connection will be persisted and multiple requests can use the same connection without handshaking each time, benefitting the session by slightly reducing request/response time.

In HTTP 1.1, connections are keep alive by default so this is the *expected* behaviour.

This happens within the session - another browser window would constitute another session, so there would be no connection sharing and therefore no benefit.

Comment: No, it's not kept open by default: "An HTTP/1.1 server MAY assume that a HTTP/1.1 client intends to maintain a persistent connection...". The actual behaviour varies by browser/server.